# Typescript interface type values to union type

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to get a union type with all type values from an interface in typescript?

For example, when an interface is given as

```
interface A {
  a: string;
  b: () => void;
  c: number;
  d: string;
  e: 'something';
}
```

the result should be

```
type B = string | () => void | number | 'something';
```

I have no clue, how I would approach this problem, if it is even possible.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use `keyof` e.g.

```
 type B = A[keyof A] // will be string | number | (() => void)
```

The type `something` will not appear since the compiler does not differentiate between the type `string` and `something` - since both are strings it will omit it in the `type B`.

Comment: Yeah, this works! But I actually wonder why. I have never read anywhere, that you can put a union type (`keyof A`) into the key brackets of an interface. Do you know, whether that is mentioned somewhere in the official docs?

Comment: @PeterLehnhardt There are two things going on here. Firstly, `keyof` returns the keys of `A`. Secondly, `A['a']` will return the type of key `a`. So it maps over the keys to get their types.

Comment: Yes, your two things are actually clear to me. The only thing, which puzzles me, is that the identity `A["a" | "b"] = A["a"] | A["b"]` (which is basically a basic form of your answer) holds true _and still does not seem to be mentioned anywhere in the typescript docs_. **And I think it's strange, that there does exist an unspoken rule in a language! What if there are other ones? How do I know about them?** So my question was actually: _Where did you find out about that rule?_

Answer (score 1):

You need something that is advance typescript.

Below example **keyof** **A** is completely interchangeable with  **string | () => void | number | 'something';**. The difference is that if you add another property to A, say myfunc: string, then keyof **A** will automatically update to be **string | () => void | number | something |myfunc**. And you can use keyof in generic contexts like pluck, where you can’t possibly know the property names ahead of time. That means the compiler will check that you pass the right set of property names to pluck:

```
pluck(A, ['number ', 'unknown']); // error, 'unknown' is not in string | () => void | number | 'something';
```

It can be

```
let B :keyof A;
```